# New Line is ignored when using a while loop in C++

Tags: c++, while-loop, newline, getline

UPDATE: I tried adding more lines with double Form Feeds, so far only the last line gets read properly, the first two does not.

I have a program that reads a file using getline() and records the page number, line number and the character location of each character in the file. The program writes each line into an array/vector like below:

```
array[1]: "abcdefg"
array[2]: "haha/fhahaha"
...
```

The line number index gets incremented as each line is read through using a for-loop to retrieve its data.

I am using a while-loop to detect if there is any Form Feed characters, so when I increase the page count, the line count reset back to 0 and character count reset back to 0.
While using the while-loop to search for form-feed characters ('\f') using the find() method (see code below), it skipped a line and I am not sure what is causing this.

```
#include <iostream>     // Basic I/O
#include <string>       // string classes
#include <fstream>      // file stream classes
#include <vector>
#include <random>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    ifstream book;

    book.open("book.txt");
    vector<string> line = { "" };
    size_t pageCount = 0;
    size_t lineCount = 0;
    size_t charCount = 0;
    size_t lineNum = 0;
    while (getline(book, line[lineNum])) {

        line.push_back(line[lineNum]);
        charCount -= charCount;
        cout << "\n Line Number: " << lineNum;
        if (line[lineNum].find('\f') == string::npos) {
            //cout << "\n BEGIN OUTTER IF";
            for (size_t n = 0; n < line[lineNum].size(); ++n) {
                charCount++;
                cout << "\n !=12: Character: " << line[lineNum].at(n) << " --  Page: " << pageCount << " line: " << lineCount << " charLoc: " << n << " charCount: " << charCount - 1;
            }
        }
        else {
            size_t nPageOffset = line[lineNum].find('\f', 0);
            while (nPageOffset != string::npos)
            {
                for (size_t n = 0; n < line[lineNum].size(); ++n) {
                    if (line[lineNum].at(n) == '\f') {
                        pageCount++;
                        charCount -= charCount;
                        lineCount -= lineCount;
                        cout << "\n ==12: Character: " << line[lineNum].at(n) << " --  Page: " << pageCount << " line: " << lineCount << " charLoc: " << n << " charCount: " << charCount - 1;
                    }
                    else if (n > line[lineNum].find('\f')) {
                        charCount++;
                        cout << "\n -1 != 12: Character: " << line[lineNum].at(n) << " --  Page: " << pageCount << " line: " << lineCount << " charLoc: " << n << " charCount: " << charCount - 1;
                    }
                    else {
                        charCount++;
                        cout << "\n WE: Character: " << line[lineNum].at(n) << " --  Page: " << pageCount << " line: " << lineCount << " charLoc: " << n << " charCount: " << charCount - 1;
                    }
                }
                size_t nPageSearchOffset = nPageOffset + 1;
                nPageOffset = line[lineNum].find('\f', nPageSearchOffset);
            }
        }
        lineNum++;
        lineCount++;
    }
    book.close();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Every Line Number gets read, except it skips line number: 13

Partial Output:

```
 Line Number: 12 charCount: 0
 ==12: Character:  --  Page: 6 line: 0 charLoc: 0 charCount: 4294967295
 ==12: Character:  --  Page: 7 line: 0 charLoc: 1 charCount: 4294967295
 -1 != 12: Character: g --  Page: 7 line: 0 charLoc: 2 charCount: 0
 -1 != 12: Character: h --  Page: 7 line: 0 charLoc: 3 charCount: 1
 -1 != 12: Character: i --  Page: 7 line: 0 charLoc: 4 charCount: 2
 -1 != 12: Character: g --  Page: 7 line: 0 charLoc: 5 charCount: 3
>>there supposed to be a newline after this 


 ==12: Character:  --  Page: 8 line: 0 charLoc: 0 charCount: 4294967295
 ==12: Character:  --  Page: 9 line: 0 charLoc: 1 charCount: 4294967295
 -1 != 12: Character: g --  Page: 9 line: 0 charLoc: 2 charCount: 0
 -1 != 12: Character: h --  Page: 9 line: 0 charLoc: 3 charCount: 1
 -1 != 12: Character: i --  Page: 9 line: 0 charLoc: 4 charCount: 2
 -1 != 12: Character: g --  Page: 9 line: 0 charLoc: 5 charCount: 3
 Line Number: 13 charCount: 0
 ==12: Character:  --  Page: 10 line: 0 charLoc: 0 charCount: 4294967295
 ==12: Character:  --  Page: 11 line: 0 charLoc: 1 charCount: 4294967295
 -1 != 12: Character: g --  Page: 11 line: 0 charLoc: 2 charCount: 0
 -1 != 12: Character: h --  Page: 11 line: 0 charLoc: 3 charCount: 1
 -1 != 12: Character: i --  Page: 11 line: 0 charLoc: 4 charCount: 2
 -1 != 12: Character: g --  Page: 11 line: 0 charLoc: 5 charCount: 3
```

Book.txt (omit line numbers if you want to test and convert \f to form feed ASCII 12)

```
Line  Content

   0  abc
   1  def\fghi
   2  abc
   3  defd\fghi
   4  ioyudef
   5  yttdef
   6  abc
   7  abci
   8  def\fghi
   9  def\fghigh
   10 \fghig
   11 hi
   12 \f\fghig
   13 \f\fghig
   14 \fghig
```

Comment: I think I found my problem, since I am using while(not found form feed keep running), so if I have multiple form feed then it will re read the same line again. If you can help confirm this

Comment: Yes, it seems it reprocesses the input of the whole line again once for every `'\f'` it finds in the line. This means that you also get the debug output multiple times for the same line.

Comment: Instead of using `std::string::find` and handling lines with `'\f'` differently than lines without, it may be easier to just process one character at a time and update `pageCount`, `lineCount` and `charCount` according to that character.

Comment: `while (getline(book, line[lineNum])) {line.push_back(line[lineNum]);` ==> `string input; while (getline(book, imput)) { line.push_back(input);`

Comment: Yes, @mch is correct. There is no need to use a `std::vector<std::string>`, because only one line is processed at a time. Therefore, you only need one `std::string`.